# Run a set number of joined select statements under a single sql query

Tags: sql, select

I have a counselling appointment website. Currently I list clients in one table, but also have couples listed by id in a second table for when they book a couples session. ie:

```
client
id_no     first    last
564       John     Smith
983       Mary     Jones
999       Mark     Fields
882       Joan     Hancock

couple
id_no    client1    client2
623      564        983
555      999        882
```

I would like to write a single select statement, using aliases, which will list out couples on a single line. Up until now, I have been doing a simple join then cleaning up the result using php after running the query, but would like to clean this up in sql so that I get a result like the following

```
id_no   first_1   last_1   first_2    last_2
623     John      Smith     Mary       Jones
555     Mark      Fields    Joan       Hancock
```

I suspect that sub queries might be involved, but can't for the life of me wrangle them to get this result.

**Update**
I just tried the following:

```
SELECT id_no,first_1,last_1,first_2,last_2 
FROM ( SELECT a.id_no AS id_no, b.first AS first_1,b.last AS last_1 
       FROM couple AS a, client AS b WHERE a.client1=b.id_no ) c1 
JOIN ( SELECT a.id_no AS id_no, b.first AS first_2,b.last AS last_2 
       FROM couple AS a, client AS b WHERE a.client2=b.id_no ) c2 ON 
       (c1.id_no=c2.id_no)
```

And am getting a message that "Column 'id_no' in field list is ambiguous". Not sure if I am on the right track

Comment: Please add any of the queries that you have "wrangled with" to the question. It doesn't matter if it isn't working - that's what we help with. But if you don't add a query it sort of looks like you haven't really tried.

Comment: as you said "I have been doing a simple join", in fact the solution is simple join too., so you should post the query you have tried so far,

Comment: I just tried the following: SELECT id_no,first_1,last_1,first_2,last_2
FROM
(
SELECT a.id_no AS id_no, b.first AS first_1,b.last AS last_1 
FROM couple AS a, client AS b
WHERE a.client1=b.id_no
) c1
JOIN
(
SELECT a.id_no AS id_no, b.first AS first_2,b.last AS last_2 
FROM couple AS a, client AS b
WHERE a.client2=b.id_no
) c2
ON (c1.id_no=c2.id_no) --And am getting a message that "Column 'id_no' in field list is ambiguous". Not sure if I am on the right track

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception because you did not specified the table alias to `id_no` as this column belongs to both tables, so SQL is not sure which column to return, so it will throw ambiguous column error.

Also you don't have to use sub queries, you just need to join client table twice with couple table, one for client1 and other one for client2 like below

```
Select cp.id_no, 
  cl1.first as first_1,
  cl1.last as last_1,
  cl2.first as first_2,
  cl2.last as last_2
From couple cp
inner join client cl1 on cl1.id_no = cp.client1
inner join client cl2 on cl2.id_no = cp.client2
```

Comment: Thanks Vinit - works perfectly. I need to go back to reading about inner joins, clearly.